# Loading to a div element with jquery after it has already been loaded

Tags: jquery

I have a page which loads its inner content using jquery and a simple navigation menu.  Because of this there is only one regularly accessed URL for the page.  My problem is that I can't seem to get content from within the loaded div to modify 'that' particular div.  For example I have something along the lines of this as my jquery loader function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// load index page when the page loads
$("#response").load("start.html");
$("#home").click(function(){
// load home page on click
    $('#response').load('start.html', function() {
        resizefunc();
    });
});
...
```

If I create an element within one of the loaded pages that links to # with an id from that loader function, clicking it simply moves the focus back to the top of the page rather than reloading my "response" div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since those navigation elements (ie `#home`) don't exist initially, binding those events on `ready` will do you no good. You'll need to [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) bind those same events or [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) them from a parent element.

This can easily be showcased by doing this simple test:

```
alert($("#home").length);
```

Which will alert `0`

---

Try this solution instead

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#response").load("start.html");
    $("#home").live("click", function(){
        $('#response').load('start.html', function() {
            resizefunc();
        });
    });
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#response").load("start.html");
    $("#response").delegate("#home", "click", function(){
        $('#response').load('start.html', function() {
            resizefunc();
        });
    });
});
```

using `live` or `delegate` to bind this selector to a click rather than a regular click event will allow the assigned function to exist for all selected elements that exist now and may exist in the future.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you for the quick response... too quick for me to select it as the correct answer.  I'll give it the check in 5 minutes.